Can WETH be deposited from one wallet to another?
I am new to cryptocurrency and I need to receive an ammount of WETH. I created a wallet on MetaMask and I would like to know if I can use the wallet address for depositing WETH, the same way we use a wallet address on an exchange platform like ByBit for depositing ETH. I mean, just copy the address and send it to the person who is going to make the deposit (and selecting the Ethereum Main Network).
Also, does that person need to have a wallet address on MetaMask too, or it isn't mandatory?
All I could find on internet was about wrapping and unwrapping ETH and no clear information about transfering WETH from one wallet to another.
This question might seem obvious, but in the context of cryptocurrencies, it's better to ask to avoid the risk of losing the transference ammount.

Yes, you can use your MetaMask wallet address to receive WETH, just like you would use it to receive ETH, i.e.,

Open MetaMask and ensure you are on the Ethereum Mainnet.
Copy your wallet address and share the copied address with the person who is going to send you WETH.
Ensure that the sender also selects the same network (i.e., Ethereum Mainnet) when sending the WETH.
The sender will need to pay gas fees for the transaction. Ensure they have enough ETH in their wallet to cover these fees.

The person sending you WETH does not need to have a MetaMask wallet. They can use any EVM-compatible cryptocurrency wallet that supports Ethereum and WETH transactions.

On my MetaMask app, there is no Ethereum Mainnet option, the only similar option is Ethereum Main Network, is it the same thing?

Yes, it’s the same.
